# Independence of events in repeated trials

Tags: independence, recurrent-events

Just a bit confused about whenever "Independent" event is used in probability/stats videos/books.

When we say an "Independent" event, are we referring to an event standalone or in relation to another event?

E.g.:
Let's suppose you have a deck of 6 cards(hearts) numbered from 1-6 and let there be an experiment of picking 2 cards one after the other but without replacement.
Sample space of this experiment would be

{(1,6),(1,5),(1,4),(1,3),(1,2)
(2,6)....................(2,1)
and so on}

If we define event **A** as getting 6 in the first place. We know that this event is an independent event.

However, if we define another event **B** as getting 6 in the second place, then we know that this is not an independent event and is dependent on event A.

So, can we say **A** is an independent standalone but **B** is not independent when compared with event **A**?

Answer (score 0):

> When we say an "Independent" event, are we referring to an event standalone or in relation to another event?

Independence is defined for two events. *Mutual* independence can be defined for 3 or more events. That is, given events $A,B,$ and $C$, they are mutually independent if $A$ is independent of $B$, $B$ is independent of $C$, and $A$ is independent of $C$.

> If we define event A as getting 6 in the first place. We know that this event is an independent event.

This statement needs to be made more precise. Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if $p(A \cap B) = p(A) \cdot p(B)$. As you have not yet defined a probability measure over your sample space, then there is no way to know for sure if "event A is an independent event". Also, does the statement "A is an independent event" mean that it is mutually independent of all other events in a sample space? Or does it mean that event A is independent of one or two other events? All of these questions are answered once a probability measure is defined over the sample space.

For a more detailed discussion of all of these concepts, see [here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_3_1_random_experiments.php).